# Getting Time Limit Exceeded on partition list problem

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

[Problem statement](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/partition-list/) -

Given a linked list and a value x, partition it such that all nodes less than x come before nodes greater than or equal to x.

You should preserve the original relative order of the nodes in each of the two partitions.

For example,

Given 1->4->3->2->5->2 and x = 3,

return 1->2->2->4->3->5.

My code complexity is O(n) and it had passed on TEST but while SUBMIT, I am getting TLE.

```
def partition(self, A, B):
        current = A
        head = A

        prev = None
        p1 = None

        while(current is not None):
            if(current.val < B):
                if(p1 is None):
                    p1 = current
                    if(prev is not None):
                        prev.next = current.next
                        p1.next = A
                    else:
                        prev = p1
                    head = p1
                else:
                    prev.next = current.next
                    current.next = p1.next
                    p1.next = current
                    p1 = current
                    prev = p1

                current = prev.next
            else:
                prev = current
                current = current.next

        return head
```

I have posted this on InterviewBit questions forum also but haven't received any response.

Can anyone please suggest any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I was assigning `prev` to `p1`, which is correct for cases when position of `current` is not changed even if it is smaller than given element, but if it get's changed then we have to move `prev` by one step.

Final code -

```
def partition(self, A, B):
        current = A
        head = A

        prev = None
        p1 = None

        while(current is not None):
            if(current.val < B):
                if(p1 is None):
                    p1 = current
                    if(prev is not None):
                        prev.next = current.next
                        p1.next = A
                    else:
                        prev = p1
                    head = p1
                else:
                    prev.next = current.next
                    current.next = p1.next
                    p1.next = current
                    p1 = current
                    if(prev.next == current):
                        prev = prev.next

                current = prev.next
            else:
                prev = current
                current = current.next

        return head
```